# Maximum in column of 2d array using divide and conquer

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, containers, divide-and-conquer

Let's assume we have an 2d array

```
1   2    3   1
5   6    4   0
0   3    2   1 
1   2    1   0
```

Is there a global way how to find a max number in column using divide and conquer technique if the length of the row wasn't same for every row?

I am referring to a step in finding a peak inside 2d array that requires this step.

On 1d array it would be something like

```
int maxNumber( vector<int> a , int min , int max ){
    if( min == max )
        return a[min];
    int mid = ( min + max)/2;
    int i   = maxNumber( a , min , mid );
    int j   = maxNumber( a , mid +1, max);
    if( i > j)
        return i;
    return j;
    } 

   vector<int> v = { 1 , 2 , 5 , 0 , 10 , 9};
   cout << maxNumber( a , 0 , a.size() -1 );
```

Now for NxN or NxM matrix we could do

```
int maxNumberCollum( vector<vector<int>> a , int row_min , int row_max , int size){
    if ( row_min == row_max ){
        return a[row_min][size];
    }

    int row = ( row_min + row_max ) / 2;
    int i   = maxNumberCollum( a , row_min , row     , size );
    int j   = maxNumberCollum( a , row + 1 , row_max , size);

    if( i > j)
        return i;
    return j;
};

 vector< vector<int> > a = { { 1 , 2 , 3 },
                             { 5 , 0 , 1 },
                             { 6 , 2 , 0 }
                           };
cout << maxNumberCollum( a , 0 , a.size() -1 , 2 )
```

with column we want to find maximum in passed as argument.

But what would be effective way how to implement it to 2d array given the fact that we do not know if the matrix (2d array ) is NxN / NxM or the length of row isn't same for every row?

Comment: Do the 1d case on each column and then the 1d case again on the results from each column?

Comment: IS D&C a must to use to solve your question?

Comment: @shole  It is not a must but i was trying to figure it out using D&C

Comment: **Typo alert**: it's a **column** - not a "collum" ..

Comment: (What is the `in column` from the title and (the first question in) this post? What does `with column we want to find maximum in passed as argument.` mean?)

Answer (score 0):

As each vector has its own size, you can use that information to find the maximum number in each row.

Where you have this line:

```
return a[row_min][size];
```

replace it with a call to your 1d function:

```
return maxNumber(a[row_min], 0, a[row_min].size() - 1)
```

Comment: this actually throws bad result. Also , wouldnt it make the asymptotic complexity a lot of higher , calling again log n function?

Comment: You have to look at each value to find the maximum in any event, so you will be always have NXM complexity. I can't see why it would throw a bad result, that is too vague a description - you should use a debugger. Also, passing the vector by value, as you have here, will cause extra copies to be made. Passing the vector by reference may be preferable.

Comment: Note that you could just do a simple nested loop rather than divide and conquer.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider a vector of vectors of different sizes, the key point is to ensure that you are not trying to access those out of their bounds.

As an example, consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

using std::cout;
using std::vector;

const int lowest_int = std::numeric_limits<int>::lowest();

int max_number_in_column( const vector<vector<int>> &a, 
                          size_t row_min, size_t row_max, size_t col)
{
    if ( row_min == row_max ) {
        return col < a[row_min].size() ? a[row_min][col] : lowest_int;
    }

    int row = ( row_min + row_max ) / 2;
    int i   = maxNumberColumn( a, row_min, row,     col);
    int j   = maxNumberColumn( a, row + 1, row_max, col);

    return i > j ? i : j;
};

int main() {
    vector<vector<int>> a = {
        { 1 , 2 , 3 },
        { 5 , 0 , 1, -8 },
        { 6 , 2 }
    };

    size_t col = 3;
    int max = max_number_in_column(a, 0, a.size() - 1, col);

    if ( max > lowest_int ) 
        cout << "The greater element of column " << col << " is " << max <<'\n';
    else
        cout << "Unable to find a maximum value in column " << col << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

What I really don't understand is why you are trying to do this using a divide and conquer technique, while it would be much easier with a common loop:

```
int max_number_in_column( const vector<vector<int>> &a , size_t col)
{
    int max = lowest_int;
    for ( auto const &row : a ) {
        if ( col < row.size()  &&  row[col] > max ) max = row[col];
    }
    return max;
};
```